Power query excel query - Search first 5 occurrences
in excel power query I have this table:
CTR N.  Claims n. Claims date   Risk Amount Managed Amount
3   123   01/12/2021    405     0
1   456   23/01/2022    405     800
1   458   02/09/2022    56      0
1   455   31/10/2022    455     0
1   467   20/11/2022    49      1230
1   477   07/12/2022    45      500
1   488   02/02/2023    45      20
1   489   10/02/2023    45      20
1   490   06/04/2023    1230        300
1   500   11/04/2023    1230        900
1   502   20/04/2023    1230        1230
1   555   05/05/2023    12      900
1   567   19/06/2023    12      90
1   589   25/06/2023    1230        90
1   599   10/07/2023    90      90
5   676   05/11/2023    0       450
5   679   23/12/2023    500     0
5   688   16/01/2024    23      23

I need to create a query where, for the first 5 claims for contract number and ordered by claims date, where risk amount or managed amount is >400 the corrispondant value is substituted by 500. When the value is not higher than 400 or is already reached the number of 5 occurrency in the same contract the value of risk amount and managed amount need to remain the same.
How can  manage this query?
Thanks for the response.
With this rule the result table will be:
CTR N.  Claims n. Claims date   Risk Amount Managed Amount
3   123   01/12/2021    500     0               
1   456   23/01/2022    500         500             <- 1 substitution for ctr n 1
1   488   02/02/2023    45      20      
1   489   10/02/2023    45      20              
1   490   06/04/2023    500     300             <- 2 substitution for ctr n 1
1   500   11/04/2023    500     500             <- 3 substitution for ctr n 1
1   502   20/04/2023    500     500             <- 4 substitution for ctr n 1
1   555   05/05/2023    12      500             <- 5 substitution for ctr n 1
1   567   19/06/2023    1240        90              <- No other subst. need to be possible  
1   589   25/06/2023    1230        90
1   599   10/07/2023    900     90
1   458   02/09/2022    56      0
1   455   31/10/2022    455     0
1   467   20/11/2022    49      1230
1   477   07/12/2022    45      500
5   676   05/11/2023    0       500             <- 1 substitution for ctr n 5
5   679   23/12/2023    500     0               <- 2 substitution for ctr n 5
5   688   16/01/2024    23      23


Your result table does not seem to correlate with your description. In particular,  why is 455 in CTR 1 not modified? It occurs before some of the ones that are modified, and has an amount > 400.
